# Change HTML Content using jQuery 3, then change it back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-manipulation

Basically, what I want to do:
When you press the `button` `#change`, the content in the `div` `#board` has to change to nothing but:

```
<h2>Hi!</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="ChangeAgain();">
```

Then when you click that `button`, it has to change back to what it used to be, that is:

```
<h2>Welcome to this page.</h2>
<p>It's quite boring in here. Why don't you click the button?</p>
<button onClick="Change();">Button for you to Click</button>
```

Here's my JavaScript (jQuery 3.2.1), which is not working.

```
$(function () {
  var inThere = "";
  function Change() {
    inThere += $("#board").html();
    $("#board").html("<h2>Hi!</h2> \n
    <button type=\"button\" onclick=\"ChangeAgain();\">")
  }
  function ChangeAgain () {
    $("#board").html(inThere);
  }
})
```

Comment: Don't wrap them in document ready handler

Comment: @Satpal Could you elaborate in an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Don't define the function in the document ready handler scope. You must be getting error like

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: Change is not defined",

```js
var inThere = "";

function Change() {
  inThere += $("#board").html();
  $("#board").html("<h2>Hi!</h2> \n <button type = \"button\" onclick=\"ChangeAgain();\">Button for you to Click</button>")
}

function ChangeAgain() {
  $("#board").html(inThere);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="board">
  <h2>Welcome to this page.</h2>
  <p>It's quite boring in here. Why don't you click the button?</p>
  <button onClick="Change();">Button for you to Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work in your snippet, or in my file.

Answer (score 0):

Your functions are not available in the global namespace, which is considered a good practice. But due to this you should not call a function from your HTML, but listen to the click event of your button in your code:

```js
$(function() {
    var inThere = "";
    var changed = false;
    var $board = $("#board");

    $board.on("click", "button", function() {
        if (changed) {
             $board.html(inThere);
        } else {
            inThere = $board.html();
            $board.html("<h2>Hi!</h2><button>Button for you to Click</button>");
        }

        changed = !changed;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="board">
  <h2>Welcome to this page.</h2>
  <p>It's quite boring in here. Why don't you click the button?</p>
  <button>Button for you to Click</button>
</div>
```